# Difference between LP optimization and GLPK optimization

Tags: constrained-optimization

I've seen two different optimizers being used, but both with a different solver. One uses `PULP_CBC_CMD` and the other uses `GLPKSolverMIP()` can someone explain to me the difference in these two optimization strategies?

Both of these optimizers are using to optimize daily fantasy sports lineups. It's basically a knapsack optimization problem. You are give X amount of roster spots and a defined salary and must fit players from each position into their corresponding roster spot while staying under the required salary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two solvers that you've mentioned both implement branch and bound methods for integer linear programming.  The differences are at the implementation level rather than in the basic algorithms being used.